# separate datetime into 2 fields in JSF2

Tags: datetime, jsf-2, frontend

I'm using JSF2 for implementing the front-end for my application

I have 2 fields:

- date (d/m/yyyy)
- time (h:mm)

the 2 textfields are here for the same field "birthday" in the managed bean

I wrote this code for the view:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.birthday}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="d/M/yyyy" />
</h:inputText>
<h:inputText value="#{bean.birthday}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="h:mm" />
</h:inputText>
```

this does not work of course as the field is set twice, once for the date and another for the time, which clears the information for the first

if any pattern is used here please help

Thank you

Comment: why not use `bean.birthdayDate` and  `bean.birthdayTime` and do a smart merge of them on server... you can also use primefaces calendar + time http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarTime.jsf or some jquery plugin

Comment: I think I will be end up doing this

Comment: This is a perfect use case for a [composite component with multiple input components](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `bean.birthdayDate` and `bean.birthdayTime` and do a *smart merge* of them on server...

You also can use primefaces *calendar + time* [Calendar - Time](http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarTime.jsf) or some jquery plugin